# CakePHP: RESTful prefixed action

Tags: rest, cakephp

I have troubles to do REST application in CakePHP, requesting **GET /admin/quote_authors/1.json** sends me to the 'view' action, not 'admin_view'.

- route.php:

  ```
  Router::parseExtensions('json');
  Router::mapResources(array(':controller'), array('prefix' => '/admin/'));
  ```
- QuoteAuthorsController.php:

  ```
  public $components = array('RequestHandler');

  public function admin_view($id) {
      var_dump('admin view');
  }

  public function view($id) {
      var_dump('view');
  }
  ```

Thanks.

Comment: You probably should remove the slashes from your prefix. E.g. `array('prefix' => 'admin')`. The prefix is the 'value' of the prefix, not the full 'path'. See the manual here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Comment: Already tried this, but it tells me: "Action QuoteAuthorsController::admin_1() could not be found."

Comment: Not sure I can help you out here, don't have much experience with mapResources() so I'd have to look into that as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Answering because I can't comment.

You seem to be missing the action part of the request **/admin/quote_authors/view/1.json**

So for other request it would be like **/admin/:controller/:action/:params** in general.

And, of course, like thaJeztah said, remove the slashes of the prefix (that's why it's giving you that error, it's considering the parameter "1" as the action it has to execute)

Comment: What error does it give you now (without the slashes and with the view)? For what I understand, Router::mapResources() receives the name of the controller and other options (look for mapResources here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html), so it should be Router::mapResources() and change defaults with Router::resourceMap(). Is the REST mapping absolutely necessary? Or can you make it work with simple Router::connect()

Comment: Hi, 
here is the json response:
{"code":"404","url":"/admin/quotes/10.json","name":"Action QuotesController::admin_10() could not be found."}. Cake automatically redirect the request to the right action when doing REST, so it doesn't need the :action part in the request. Doing REST with angularjs was pretty easy, but i think im gonna user basic routes for now. Thanks

Comment: Some usefull link about this issue:
http://blog.rudylee.com/2012/11/28/no-prefix-support-for-mapresources-in-cakephp-2-x/

Comment: He has a solution editing the core Router (not the best way), but it works.

Comment: Didn't know about the problem with prefixes on REST, thanks for pointing it out :) It's true that's not the best way when you have to change a library code, but as long as the future updates don't interfere with it, you're good.